# R2DBC and liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, spring-webflux, r2dbc

So starting a new project and i want to use r2dbc and webflux, been looking into what support there is to handle database migration. The last answer i could find here was from july 2019 that liquibase does not support R2DBC and after googling, this seems to still be the case.

The dream would be to use `r2dbc-h2` while developing locally, and then use something like postgres during production. Liquibase would manage the table structure both locally and in production.

Been trying to google a bit about how such a setup would look like and there is very little information out there.

I have been thinking about setting up the tables using the `liquibase-maven-plugin`, but i don't know if that will work with `r2dbc-h2`.

So several questions:

- How to setup so that liquibase uses a regular driver during migration, while the rest of the application uses the reactive driver?
- if using the maven plugin can this be used with H2 or do i need postgres as a docker?

This is a very black hole for me, does any have any information?

Comment: FWIW, there's a ticket open at Liquibase for R2DBC support: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3419. You might want to leave a comment there.

Comment: yes i have seen it and it has not been updated since `April 26, 2019, 10:05 AM` and there is no way to leave comments there.

Comment: Meh, you're right. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think there should be no problem using 2 drivers in application. As liquibase uses standard jdbc driver you can configure it to use that one for migrations and configure r2dbc to run the application. Maybe some tweeks needs to be done but I would start with something like:

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
    user: postgres
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
    username: postgres
```

and include both libraries:

```
io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql
org.postgresql:postgresql
```

If there is error keep us posted.

note: for testing you can use testcontainers or embedded postgresql also

Comment: I’ll look into it, for now im using the liquibase maven plugin to execute it during runtime and it works okey. Would be better though to be anle to verify database integrity during application startup than during build time.

Comment: I can confirm that the suggested approach works. I tried with h2 and managed to run migration on startup using flyway.

Answer (score 4):

Complementing @bilak's answer, you must add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I was facing the same problem and I had added the properties `user` and `URL` to Liquibase configuration on my application.yml, and then Spring started to claim about one class not found, adding this dependency solved the issue

Comment: After adding the above dependency still, I was getting the following error msg:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/dbname does not start with the r2dbc scheme`

To resolve that I need to explicitly specify the DB configuration in the Configuration class and add @EnableR2dbcRepositories

Comment: for R2DBC you need to use it for example
  ** url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/localdatabase?currentSchema=public
   username: mypostgres
   password: admin**

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Boot 2.6.3 with Spring Framework 5.3.15, the following configuration works for R2DBC with Liquibase

##### **build.gradle** snippet

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    //database
    implementation "io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql"
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    //liquibase
    implementation "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc'

    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}
```

##### application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: REACTIVE
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb
    username: postgres
  liquibase:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb
```

Comment: `web-application-type: REACTIVE` is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Maven dependencies required for integration

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${r2dbc-postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Applcation.yml configuration

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
   username: postgres
   password: password1
   url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5433
  liquibase:
   url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres
   user: postgres
   password: password1
   change-log: liquibase-changeLog.xml
```

Nothing else is required no manual beans or any other configuration is required

Comment: Isn't jdbc driver needed?

Comment: JDBC driver is not required and it worked for me too with the above config. Liqibase have its own dependecies which pull the jars (transitive dependecies) for the liquibase to work. Thank you so much @Ishant choukse