# How to integrate liquibase with spring data reactive?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, liquibase, r2dbc

Have anybody tried to integrate liquibase with spring reactive stack? From what I've googled, liquibase still doesn't support r2dbc driver and it requires you to add both spring data jdbc & r2dbc dependencies. It works well with an empty project - but if there are already any repositories, both spring data jdbc & r2dbc try to resolve them and application fails. Perhaps there's a way to disable spring data jdbc repositories so it only works with the liquibase?

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555217/r2dbc-and-liquibase/62578933#62578933)

Comment: Works as expected: https://github.com/AndreasKl/todo-reactive

Comment: Why not just stick with JDBC for Liquibase usage, and use reactive querying only for your own queries?