# Spring boot r2dbc and jdbc Liquibase does not update on application start

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, liquibase, r2dbc

I want my application to use r2dbc drive when running and jdbc to handle the database with Liquibase. I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555217/r2dbc-and-liquibase) as a reference. It is possible by adding the correct configuration inside `application.properties` and `build.gradle.kts` to achieve that. Update and everything is working but not automatically. Do you have any suggestions?[Spring's reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.migration-tool.liquibase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to use db migrations like Liquibase in a R2bc application.

1. Till now Liquibase did not support R2dbc, and **by default** R2dbc and Jdbc can not be activated in a single Spring boot application. In a reactive Spring Boot application, although you added a Jdbc starter, it is not activated by default.

   But you can setup liquibase in a R2dbc application, and configure Liquibase Maven/Gradle plugin to migrate the database **manually** by Gradle tasks/Maven goals.  See my example: [liquibase-maven-r2dbc](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/db-migrations/liquibase-maven-r2dbc), make sure the db is running, and execute `mvn liquibase:update` in the project root.

   See the official guide of Liquibase Maven Plugin, https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/workflows/using-liquibase-maven-plugin-and-springboot.html

   Both Liquibase/flyway provides standalone CLI tools, if your database migration scripts is outside of a project(or as a specific project just includes the scripts), and is maintained by dbamin or via CI/CD pipeline. The CLI is a good option. Thus it separates scripts from your main project.
2. Use [R2dbc Migrate](https://github.com/nkonev/r2dbc-migrate) directly, it is similar to Flyway but working with 2rdbc. See my example: [r2dbc-migrate](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/db-migrations/r2dbc-migrate).

**Update**: In the latest Spring Boot 3.x, it seems it is possible to setup Liquibase/flyway in a WebFlux project, you have to add jdbc driver and setup connection config(DO NOT use datasource). But I would like to use R2dbcMigrate which is designated to Reactive stack.