# When doing R2DBC with Liquibase how do you ensure Liquibase finishes first before doing any R2DBC operations?

Tags: java, spring, liquibase, r2dbc

When doing [R2DBC and liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555217/r2dbc-and-liquibase) how do you ensure Liquibase finishes first before doing any R2DBC operations?

I have a `@PostConstruct` which seems to get fired before Liquibase finishes.

I am thinking I just need a `@DependsOn` but I am not sure what to depend on.

Comment: share some config it's hard to follow what you'd like to do

Answer (score 1):

A `liquibase` bean is completed after the Liquibase finishes its run

So you just need

```java
@Component
@DependsOn("liquibase")
```

Since it's a string, there's no need to load up liquibase-core as an `implementation` depenendecy and you can use it as a `runtimeOnly` dependency to save memory on your IDE.