# Run liquibase before r2dbc

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, r2dbc

I know I can run [R2DBC and liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555217/r2dbc-and-liquibase) together, but I was wondering how do you ensure that Liquibase gets run first?

r2dbc-mysql driver doesn't have support for creating the database if it is missing so it fails on startup unless the database is present

Comment: Maybe I don't get your question? The database should exist before the application is started. Liquibase should only create/modify DDL. And there is some startup lifecycle in spring so Liquibase should be executed before the application is in `ready` state.

Comment: liquibase uses the JDBC mysql driver which allows for the creation of the database which the r2dbc driver does not support.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly Spring Boot/R2dbc supports `schema.sql` and `data.sql` in the classpath to initialize the database at the application startup.

Check my example project: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/boot/src/main/resources

For db migration in the development stage, try to use [r2dbc-migrate](https://github.com/nkonev/r2dbc-migrate) instead if you are using Spring WebFlux/R2dbc in your projects.

For Spring Boot project, just need to add [r2dbc-migrate-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/nkonev/r2dbc-migrate/tree/master/r2dbc-migrate-spring-boot-starter) into your project deps.

R2dbc Migrate is more similar to Flyway, you can simply put the migration scripts to  classpath `db/migration` with version numbers.

```bash
+main
  +resouces
    +db
      +migration
        - V1__add_column_xxx.sql
        - V2__add_table_xxx.sql
```

Check my example project: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/r2dbc-migrate/src/main/resources/db/migration